# Find closely matching data using multiple columns

Tags: r

So I have two data frames:

```
d <- data.frame(ID_COLUMN = c(45777,45778,45779,45780), 
                column2 = c("PRIMARY","SECONDARY","COLLEGE","COLLEGE"),  
                column3 = c("RURAL","URBAN","RURAL","RURAL"),  
                Number_of_pupils = c(101, 170,180,2000) )

d2 <- data.frame(ID_COLUMN = c(NA,NA,NA,NA), 
                 column2 = c("PRIMARY","COLLEGE","PRIMARY","COLLEGE"),  
                 column3 = c("URBAN","RURAL","RURAL","RURAL"),  
                 Number_of_pupils = c(110, 300,200,2000))
```

(Sample dataset, I will be dealing with a much larger one)

For D2 dataframe  I need to complete the ID Column to replace the 'na' values. I must use d1 dataframe to find an exact match for column 2 and column 3 and for number_of_pupils it to be within +/- 10% match. There may be multiple matches so if possible find the ID with closest number of pupils..

Would be very grateful for any help, I am new to this so yes I know I've probably formatted my question not great. -Sorry I could get it to paste as a code format either.

I started thinking about doing this as a function but soon realised this wasn't going to work:

```
URN_NODATAFUNCTION <- function(DAT1,DAT2,COLUMN1A,COLUMN2A,COLUMN3A, COLUMN1B,COLUMN2B,COLUMN3B, COLUMN4B) 
  {
  OUT <- DAT1 %>%
    mutate_if(urn_match_nodata =  DAT1$COLUMN1A = DAT1$COLUMN1B & DAT1$COLUMN2A = DAT1$COLUMN2B 
                                        & DAT1$COLUMN3A/DAT2$COLUMN3B < 1.1 & DAT1$COLUMN3/DAT2$COLUMN3B >0.9 ~ DAT1$COLUMN4B ~ ))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first join by those 2 columns, and then filter out the matches that are outside of the range you specified for the number of pupils.

```
library(dplyr)

d2 |> 
  select(-ID_COLUMN) |> 
  left_join(d, by = join_by(column2, column3)) |> 
  filter(Number_of_pupils.x <= Number_of_pupils.y * 1.1, 
         Number_of_pupils.x >= Number_of_pupils.y * 0.9)
```